# HTML: How to refer to span.title inside a class?

Tags: html, scrapy

I am building a webscraper and I have this block of HTML code:

```
<div class = 'example-1'
     <ul class = 'example-2'
         <li>
             <span title = 'data1' > 155 </span>
                  /
             <span title = 'data2' > 155 </span>
```

And I want to scrape the numbers 155 and 145 inside the span title

In my code using scrapy, I identified this as:

```
'size': detail.css('ul.example-2 ::text').get(),
```

but it is not returning me anything. How do I fix this?

Comment: You can put values in html using content: "" in css but you can't go the other way and take the value out again. For that you need JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct CSS selectors are:

- `span[title="data1"]`
- `span[title="data2"]`

Alternatively, you can select both at the same time with:

- `span[title^="data"]`

I am unfamiliar with scrapy syntax, but I believe your scrapy selector should look  something like this:

```
response.css('span[title^="data"]::text').getall()
```

---

**Further info:**

In CSS, square brackets denotes the attribute selector.

You can select:

- an element with an attribute : `span[title]`
- an element with a specific attribute-value : `span[title="data1"]`
- an element with the *start pattern* of an attribute-value : `span[title^="data"]`
- an element with the *end pattern* of an attribute-value : `span[title$="1"]`

and more.

Comment: Great comprehensive answer, I didn't know about the _pattern_ selectors!

Comment: There are several more (`*`|`$`|`~` etc.). You can find a full list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors